# How to make the MacApp window background transparent or semi-transparent when you can use Xcode12's .command

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In Xcode11, it was possible to make the background of the application window transparent from NSWindow.
In Xcode12, you can use AppKit App Delegate to make
'window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)'
I know that the background color will change if you write
I want to use the new ".command" added in Xcode12.
In order to do so, I think I'll have to use the SwiftUI App, but is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I changed the ContentView to EmptyView and reduced the size of the first ContentView and then called another window with onAppear, so it worked.